# Double slash is being added by the host to folders

Tags: html, css

I have a problem whenever i upload my website to the root folder the host adds a slash / to the folders of CSS and js like this:

```
<link href="//css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and when I move the everything to a folder like www.site.com/site
everything works fine!!  Any suggestions? do I need to do something in the htaccess file? 
I greatly appreciate any insight.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried css/bootstrap.min.css? No first slash.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what platform you are hosting on (and tag it as such), sounds like that's central to the problem here.